# Bootstrap - Footer <ul> not aligned on mobile screen?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have an  in the footer which shows fine on desktop, but on mobile it is aligned on the right of the screen. Can anyone figure out how to fix it? Thanks

```
    <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div style="float:none;margin:0 auto;" id="toplist" class="col-md-12 col-xs-3 text-center">
             <ul >
                <a style="color:white;" href="https://example.com/"><li id="first" style="list-style:none;display: inline;">HOME</li></a>
                <a style="color:white;" href="https://example.com/service"><li style="list-style:none;display: inline;padding-left:30px;">SERVICE</li></a>
                <a style="color:white;" href="https://example.com/examples"><li style="list-style:none;display: inline;padding-left:30px;">EXAMPLES</li></a>
                <a style="color:white;" href="https://example.com/order"><li style="list-style:none;display: inline;padding-left:30px;">ORDER</li></a>
                <a style="color:white;" href="https://example.com/contact"><li style="list-style:none;display: inline;padding-left:30px;">CONTACT</li></a>
             </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="hello" class="col-md-12 col-xs-9 text-center">
      © 2017 site.com
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Are you resetting the default margin that `ul` tags have?

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

Desktop:

[image]

Mobile:

[image]

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!--removed classes-->
      <div style="float:none;margin:0 auto;" id="toplist">
        <ul>
          <a style="color:white;" href="https://example.com/">
            <li id="first" style="list-style:none;display: inline;">HOME</li>
          </a>
          <a style="color:white;" href="https://example.com/service">
            <li style="list-style:none;display: inline;padding-left:30px;">SERVICE</li>
          </a>
          <a style="color:white;" href="https://example.com/examples">
            <li style="list-style:none;display: inline;padding-left:30px;">EXAMPLES</li>
          </a>
          <a style="color:white;" href="https://example.com/order">
            <li style="list-style:none;display: inline;padding-left:30px;">ORDER</li>
          </a>
          <a style="color:white;" href="https://example.com/contact">
            <li style="list-style:none;display: inline;padding-left:30px;">CONTACT</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--added new <div>-->
    <div class="row">
      <div id="hello" class="col-md-12 col-xs-9 text-center">
        © 2017 site.com
      </div>
      <!--added </div>-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--</div>-->
</footer>
```